# Using semantic version with trunk based development for Python package

Tags: python, version-control, versioning, release-management, semantic-versioning

I am trying to understand trunk based development with semantic versioning for a Python project. Has anyone had any experience of adopting a trunk based development with semantic versioning for packages?

I store the semantic version in `version.py:__version__`

On the trunk (main) `version.py:__version__` would be `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and on the CI server each build would append the build number, e.g. `1.0.0.1234-SNAPSHOT`. A change log would initially be empty for the semantic version number on the trunk (main).

When ready to release, a release branch would be created `release-1.0.x` and any bug fixes, would be cherry-picked from trunk(main). A gitlab CI job would still run tests for commits on branches named `release-`. The release branch may be tagged, e.g. `1.0.1`, `1.0.2` etc. until the release stabilises. This would bump the version number in `version.py`.

The change log could be finalised on the release-branch, however this would mean that it would have to be merged back to trunk (main). File `version.py` would also presumably have to be merged back to trunk after it is has been bumped following hot fixes on the release branch. Is a merge from release to trunk(main) acceptable in trunk based development for change log and version files only?

The problem would be if a new release, e.g. `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT`, was then prepared for, while release branch `1.0.x` was still active. Then the version number would be out of synch between trunk and release.

How is this managed with trunk based development approach?

Comment: you cant cherry pick features

Comment: Done, thanks @Ewan. Any advice on achieving semantic versioning with trunk based development? Is it possible?

Comment: you cant cherry pick fixes either

Comment: Hi @Ewan According to [TBD: Branch For Release](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/) - section "Fix Production Bugs on Trunk", the model suggests that it is ok to fix and test on the trunk(main) and cherry pick these to a release branch, but not vice versa?

Comment: yes they are very wrong indeed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92357/discussion-between-dcs3spp-and-ewan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it as follows with Semantic versioning Major.Minor.Patch.Build where {buildnumber} is replaced out by the CI with a ever increasing build number for the project as a whole and the CI build adds "-snapshot" or "-alpha" or whatever to distinguish non release builds.

```
Trunk
  program features
  v1.0.0.{buildnumber}
  program features
  v1.1.0.{buildnumber}
Release_1_1_x
  v1.1.0.{buildnumber}
  a fix is applied
  v1.1.1.{buildnumber}
  etc
Trunk
  v1.2.0.{buildnumber}
  program features and fixes
Release_1_2_x
  v1.2.0.{buildnumber}
  a fix is applied
  v1.2.1.{buildnumber}
  etc
Trunk
  v1.3.0.{buildnumber}
  ....
```

No merges, no cherry picking

Comment: Thanks for responding @Ewan, appreciated. Ok, I think I understand... so version held in version.py file would be patch bumped on each release branch and not merged back to trunk. On the trunk, version.py would be bumped for major/minor changes. Trying to understand the cherry-picking issue though....what happens if fix needs to be available on trunk and future releases also?

Comment: you have to do it twice

Comment: Thanks @Ewan, will try out versioning approach and accept answer.....